# ListView list - reference variable or object?

Tags: java, android, findviewbyid, setcontentview

When I create a class, let's assume `class A`, that the actual object should be created and the memory allocated to it, I have to perform the following procedure:

```
A a = new A();
```

And at this moment, via the variable a, I can refer directly to the object.

However, when I have a situation:

```
ListView list;
list = findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

Is an object created during the list variable declaration? Could someone comment on this? Because with this statement I met in one tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

All variables reference to object in Java.

For your example:

```java
ListView list;
list = findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

The first statement won't create any new object, i.e.: `findViewById` won't create a new instance of `ListView`, actually, `ListView` object was created during the phase when you call `setContentView(R.layout.xx)`, under the hood the Android traverse through the layout XML and create corresponding objects for each tag.

So after `setContentView(xx)`, you already have a `ListView` instance in memory.

When you perform `list = findViewById(R.id.listview)`, the method `findViewById` returns the reference of the `ListView`, and pass the reference to `list`, so the list now refers to the `ListView` object.

If you want to know it more clear, I suggest reading the related chapter in `Head First Java`, which clarifies this relationship clearly.

Answer (score 1):

@LiuWenbin_NO's answer perfectly describes the situation. However, I thought I might put some more info regarding this.

`setContentView` creates the `View` instances when called in the `onCreate` function of an `Activity`. It takes a layout resource Id or a single `View` as a parameter and inflates the view. To understand more clearly, only the `setContentView` is enough for your `Activity` to have the Android screen populated with the static views that you have designed in your layout file right? Hence if you want to modify something in your layout, you take the references of your views and modify the views accordingly.

`Listview list;` only creates a variable of `ListView` type (note that every layout instances extends `View`). When you have called the `setContentView` function, it creates the references of the views inflated and using the `findViewById`, you are just getting the references of those.

Previously we had to cast to specific view types while using `findViewById` which is not necessary for newer versions of Android SDK. Hence the object is not created when you have declared `ListView list`, it was created when you called `setContentView`.

If you want to create instances of your views first and then want to inflate that, you can do that using `setContentView` as well. For example, take a look at the following code.

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
setContentView(tv); 

// Modify the TextView? 
tv.setText("Hello there");
```

In this way, you can only pass a single view instance to the `setContentView` function. Hence to achieve a complex layout with multiple controls you need to use the layout.

Using layout resources with `setContentView` decouples your application logic from the presentation layer.

I highly recommend [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZthJlG4o-2wC&lpg=PA87&ots=vCrrlerRHE&pg=PA87&output=embed) for better understanding.